# Adding an Image to a SharePoint Online Table

Tags: modern-experience, modern-pages, image, table

I'm trying to find a way I can add an image to a table created on a modern page.  I've researched this, and most people say it's not possible.  So I'm wondering if there might be either a way to add an image to a table's cell, or if anyone has an alternative idea, that would be very helpful.  Here's the table:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any obvious way, but you can paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) an image directly into the table. You don't have any real options after that (so make sure you image is the correct size, cropped, etc. ahead of time).

[image: screenshot of image in table]

Keep in mind that the image will not be uploaded but rather linked from the location you copied it. So, upload your images to a document library ahead of time then open them and right-click and choose Copy Image from there. This will ensure that users have access to the images and that they aren't hotlinked from the web somewhere where they could be changed or become inaccessible.

Comment: As soon as I saw a pic of a horse and then Wowee. I knew it was you!
I LOVE your videos - learn so much from you, but even more so your sense of humor and personality. Thanks for being a Rock Star!!